# How do I check if a tuple is only made up of two numbers?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to make a function that makes sure that my tuple is only made up of zeros or ones.

```
def zero_um(maze):
    for i in range(len(maze)):
        if maze[i]==0 and maze[i]==1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

However this will always lead to false because a numer can't be one and zero at the same time.
But if i try:

```
def zero_um(tpl):
    for i in range(len(tpl)):
        if tpl[i]==0 or tpl[i]==1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

but that accepts asnwers like (1,2)
I've also tried with using != but ran into similar dilemas

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each value in the tuple, and if it is not 0 or 1, return False.

```
for value in mytuple:
    if value not in [0,1]:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: The important part here is that the `return True` is on a different indentation level than the `return False`. When you speak out the "otherwise return true" in English, you cannot hear which of the possible indentation levels is meant. This may be the source of the OP's confusion.

Comment: That basically comes down to `all(0 <= x <= 1 for x in maze)` (or similarly with `in`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set(maze) <= {0, 1}`.

By the way returning `True` or `False` in `if` branches is never a good idiom since you can just return the expression itself:

```
return set(maze) <= {0, 1}
```

instead of

```
if set(maze) <= {0, 1}:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question, I thought all items need to be distinct. Updated.

Comment: Your first example makes no sense. It will only test the first element, and will always return `False`.

Comment: @ekhumoro That example is copied from the OP where I wanted to point out that it's better to return the expression rather than open if/else branches that return `True` or `False`. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
def zero_um(tpl):
    return all(x in [0, 1] for x in tpl)
```

`x in [0, 1]` checks if something is 0 or 1, `... for x in tpl` performs this for every element `x`, and `all` makes sure they are all true, otherwise it returns false.

Alternatively we can write:

```
def zero_um(tpl):
    return set(tpl) <= {0, 1}
```